# Tiptap how to create a paragraph (p) on Shift-Enter, instead of a br?

Tags: tiptap

Using TipTap, I'm trying to avoid adding a `<br />`, but create a `<p></p>` instead, with the focus inside that `<p>|</p>` when the user hit `shift-Enter` but I can't make it work.

Here's what I did so far:

```
new (class extends Extension {
    keys () {
        return {
            'Shift-Enter' (state, dispatch, view) {
                const { schema, tr } = view.state
                const paragraph = schema.nodes.paragraph

                console.log(tr.storedMarks)
                const transaction = tr.deleteSelection().replaceSelectionWith(paragraph.create(), true).scrollIntoView()
                view.dispatch(transaction)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
})()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In TipTap 2.0 I am able to use this custom extension:

```
const ShiftEnterCreateExtension = Extension.create({
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      "Shift-Enter": ({ editor }) => {
        editor.commands.enter();
        return true;
      },
    };
  },
});
```

To make shift + enter behave like enter.

In my case I actually wanted enter to do something different. So I use prosemirror events to set a ref flag on whether shift was pressed. Than I check that flag under the "Enter" keyboard event -- which could be triggered normally or through the shift + enter extension.

Comment: This is great solution! Working as expected, however got one question or extension to this solution.

How can we in this case enable only shift + enter for making new lines, while Enter shouldn't do anything?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant but as I was looking for the same thing, I found two ways to make this work.

NOTE:
I'm using tiptap v2, if that's not a problem, then:

I overrode the HardBreak extension, since it's the one that use the `Shift-Enter` keybinding. It looks something like;

```js
const CustomHardBreak = HardBreak.extend({
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      "Mod-Enter": () => this.editor.commands.setHardBreak(),
      "Shift-Enter": () => this.editor.commands.addNewline(),
    };
  },
});
```

And used it like so;

```js
editor = new Editor({
  extensions: [
    customNewline,
    CustomHardBreak,
  ]
});
```

1. Use the default editor command `createParagraphNear`. E.g `this.editor.commands.createParagraphNear()`
2. I tried creating a custom extension from your code and ended up with something similar to the command above, i.e;

```js
export const customNewline = Extension.create({
  name: "newline",
  priority: 1000, // Optional
  addCommands() {
    return {
      addNewline:
        () =>
        ({ state, dispatch }) => {
          const { schema, tr } = state;
          const paragraph = schema.nodes.paragraph;

          const transaction = tr
            .deleteSelection()
            .replaceSelectionWith(paragraph.create(), true)
            .scrollIntoView();
          if (dispatch) dispatch(transaction);
          return true;
        },
    };
  },
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      "Shift-Enter": () => this.editor.commands.addNewline(),
    };
  },
});
```

And added this as an extension in my editor instance.

PS:
They both work, almost exactly the same, I haven't found a difference yet. But there's somewhat of a 'catch' if you would call it that; Both these methods don't work on empty lines/nodes, a character has to be added before the cursor for it to work, any character, even a space.

Comment: This really great! Thanks a lot. For me, only the second solution works, but it works great.